# what are meanpoints and how do I generate them

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have two images (see below) and an `H` affine transformation I generated from my own implementation of least mean square and RANSAC. I want to use [this code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48135-image-warping) for the `imwarp()` part.

In his explanation the author states that `cornerPoints` is a vector of `meanpoints`. I have researched and am failing to understand what are meanpoints and how do I generate these from my images?

I am working with these images converted to LAB:
[image][image]

Comment: is there a particular reason why you aren't using `imwarp` from the Image Processing Toolbox? Just curious to know if you're trying to figure out how things work, or if there's something in `imwarp` that doesn't suit your problem.

Comment: trying to implement my own imwarp.